# How to use algorithms in neo4j 4.x.x

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to use a specific new feature in 4.x.x. However most of the algorithm plugins are not supported. What's the alternative when using this version for a database? Currently I'm interested in the ability to find the shortest path between two nodes in 4.x.x

Comment: Would either the [shortestpath or allshortestpath](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path) functions suffice?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need.